# How to use environmentName or other configuration to generate different jars based on lifecycle environment

Tags: java, gradle

How to use environmentName or other configuration to generate different jars based on lifecycle environment. I want to generate weather-service-dev.jar or weather-service.prod.jar based on the git branch which is being built.

```
settings.gradle
rootProject.name=weather-service
```

environmentName doesn't help me handle this
https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.7/tools/gradle/set-up-gradle-for-diff-envs.html

Is there a way to customize settings.gradle per environment